# DataTable Sorting on Firefox Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, firefox, datatable

"Sorting DataTable is not working on Firefox browser". It is working properly when running on the Chrome browser, but It is not working with Firefox. The issue when using Firefox after the page load and clicking the sorting column the first time it works but when clicking the sorting column for the second time it is not doing any things.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setUpTable();
});

function setUpTable() {
    var skipAjax          = false;
    var skipAjaxDrawValue = 0;
    var isSortAscending   = true;

    table = $("#paymentTable").DataTable({
        bProcessing: false,
        bSort: false,
        destroy: true,
        dom: '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">', // remove built-in search input box/label
        info: false,
        paging: false,
        serverSide: true,
        stateSave: true,
        targets: "no-sort",
        ajax: {
            dataType: "JSON",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/BeneficiaryPayment/Search",
            data: function (data) {
                if (skipAjax) {
                    skipAjaxDrawValue = data.draw;
                }
                return data;
            },
            beforeSend: function () {                        
                if (skipAjax) {                             
                    const lastResponse = table.ajax.json(); 
                    lastResponse.draw  = skipAjaxDrawValue; 
                    isSortAscending    = !isSortAscending;

                    lastResponse.data.sort((r1, r2) => r1.TransactionDate < r2.TransactionDate ? isSortAscending ? -1 : 1 : -1);
                    adjustSortIcon(isSortAscending);
                    this.success(lastResponse); 
                    skipAjax = false;           
                    return false;
                }
                showSpinner();
                return true;
            },
            complete: function () {
                removeSpinner();
            }
        },
        aoColumns: [
            {
                className: "details-control",
                orderable: false,
                data: null,
                defaultContent: "",
                render: (data) => {
                    if (!data.Beneficiaries?.length && !data.ForwardDrawdowns?.length) return "";
                    const plus_sign = data.ForwardDrawdowns?.length > 0
                        ? "plus-sign-secondary"
                        : "plus-sign";

                    return `<i class="flag ${plus_sign} hasPointer" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
                }
            },
            { mDataProp: (_data, _type, full) => getActionButtons(_data) },
            { mDataProp: "DisplayTransactionDate" },
            { mDataProp: (_data, _type, full) => getEditClientLink(_data) },
            { mDataProp: "ClientId" },
            { mRender: (_data, _type, full) => getTradeTransactionLink(full) },
            { mDataProp: "DisplaySoldAmount" },
            { mRender: (_data, _type, full) => getDisplayBoughtAmount(full) },
            { mDataProp: "Destination" },
            { mDataProp: "PaymentMethod" },
            { mDataProp: "Partner" },
            { mRender: (_data, _type, full) => getDisplayPaymentStatus(full["DisplayPaymentStatus"]) },
            { mRender: (_data, _type, full) => getDisplayRiskGrade(full["DisplayRiskGrade"]) }
        ],
        initComplete: function() {
            $("#btnSearch").on("click", e => {
                const searchText = $("#search").val().trim();
                window.localStorage.setItem(searchTextKey, searchText);

                const paymentStatus = $("#paymentStatuses").val();
                window.localStorage.setItem(paymentStatusKey, paymentStatus);

                table.columns(0).search(searchText);
                table.columns(1).search(paymentStatus);

                isSortAscending = true;
                adjustSortIcon(isSortAscending);
                table.draw();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            table.on("click",
                "th.sortable",
                function() {
                    skipAjax = true;
                    table.draw();
                }
            );
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            { type: "currency", targets: [colSoldAmount, colBoughtAmount ] }
        ],
        rowCallback: rowCallback
    });

    
}

function adjustSortIcon(isSortAscending) {
    const cell = $("th.sortable", 0);
    if (isSortAscending) {
        cell.removeClass("sorting_desc");
        cell.addClass("sorting_asc");
    } else {
        cell.removeClass("sorting_asc");
        cell.addClass("sorting_desc");
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="paymentTable" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="sortable sorting_asc">Transaction Date</th>
                        <th>Client</th>
                        <th>Client Id</th>
                        <th>Deal Id</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Client Sold</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Client Bought</th>
                        <th>Destination</th>
                        <th>Payment Method</th>
                        <th>Partner</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Payment Status</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Risk Grade</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

Comment: I tried to sort other column that is not date time incase it might be the datetime format issue but it not. It also has the same issue when change sorting to Client Id instead.

Answer (score 0):

Data tables working properly in every browser, I just test out in firefox it works properly make sure you have added latest scripts and links for data table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).